# use rand1 to implement randx

Tags: function, math, random

You have `int rand1()` which outputs 0 or 1 in equal probability.

You need to implement `int randx(int x)` which outputs 0,1,2,3,4,...,x, each value should in equal probability.

It is easy to set bits based on `rand1` output for functions like `rand3` or `rand7`. For `rand3`, just call `rand1` twice and set bit 0 and 1 based on the output and 00,01,10,11 will have equal probability to get select (25%). But how about functions like `rand4`?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways

Comment: hi martianwars, I edited the question to mention that `randx` should output 0,1,...,x in equal probability, that is why I think your previous approach might not work.

Comment: see the new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. You will need to generate a binary number bigger than the one you need by concatenating random bits.  But then unless `x+1` is a power of 2, you'll need to use [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) to ensure each value is returned by `randx` with equal probability. To make the probabilily of rejection small, say less than 2^-p, the power of 2 you generate should have `p+1` bits more than necessary. The method of rejection will look like:

```
int rand(int x) {
  choose b such that m = 2^b >= x+1 
  let r_max = m - m mod (x+1)
  do {
    r = base-2 number of r pseudo-random bits
  } while (r > r_max)
  return r mod (x+1)
}
```

Note that when `x+1` is a power of 2, the loop always executes exactly once. When it's not, the probability of each iteration depends on `b`. Adding 1 to `b` halves the probability of another iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem you will need to keep a few dummy outputs (rejection sampling, as @Gene pointed out) on which you repeat the experiment performed.

I have provided two implementations here. The **first one is sub-optimal**, but easier to understand. The **second one is more optimal** but a little more difficult. Finally, I've tried to **outline a proof and linked to a Math StackExchange answer**.

---

**First Approach** -

Step 1 - Run `rand1()` `x + 1` times.

Step 2 - Check if the output is one-hot. By one-hot I mean, only 1 of the `x + 1` runs results in `1` and all the others `0`. If not so, repeat Step 1. Else go to Step 3.

Step 3 - Print index of 1 as your output.

The python code will look like this -

```
def randx(x):
    choice = -1
    while choice == -1:
        for i in range(0, x+1):
            c = rand1()
            if c == 1 and choice == -1:
                choice = i
            elif c == 1 and choice != -1:
                choice = -1
                break
```

---

**Second Approach** -

Of course, the first method is sub-optimal. You can make this far better, but it will need a lot more code. Let's say we want to do a prediction between `x+1` values (`0` to `x`). You will need to carry out the experiment atleast `k = ceil(log(x+1))` times. Now, each of the outcomes will have an equal probability of `1 / 2^k`.

Out of these `2^k` possibilities, assign some to numbers (due to our choice of `k`, you will see that you can assign a number to atleast half the possibilities). Call the other possibilities **dummy** output.

When you get a **dummy** output, you simply repeat the experiment. If you don't, you output the number corresponding to that output.

As an example, if x = 4, x + 1 = 5. Hence we need `k = 3`. Assign 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 their binary representations (000 to 101) and leave the remaining 3 as dummies. The pseudo code will look like this,

```
function randx(x):
    choice = -1
    runs = ceil(log(x+1))
    while choice == -1:
        output = 0
        for i in range(0, runs):
            output += pow(2, i)*rand1()
        if output <= x:
            choice = output
```

---

**Why does this work?**

We are giving all numbers equal probable events. If none of those events happen, we are simply repeating this experiment. If you look at the total probability of getting a number `i`,

```
Let p = 1 / 2^k
Let q = 1 - (x+1)*p
Total probability of getting i = p + q*p + q*q*p + q*q*q*p ...
= p/(1-q)
= 1/(x+1)
Hence this sums up to 1 / (x+1).
```

For a more complete explanation with MathJax, refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356/is-it-possible-to-split-coin-flipping-3-ways

Comment: cool, but I think the choice that you make will be in probability of `(x+1)/2^(x+1)`, eg: for `rand4`, you will pick 10000, 01000, 00100, 00010, 00001, among `2^5` possibilities.

Comment: No I was referring to the second optimal approach in the third section

Comment: The second approach does not do the experiment x+1 times, it does it ceil(log(x+1)) times

Comment: For your first approach, I think it again, now I think your first approach will work, for 10000, 01000, 00100, 00010, and 00001 these 5 options, you are picking it in a random flavor, so it is 1/5.

Comment: Yeah both will work, but first is sub optimal. Use the second if efficiency is a concern